# How do I change the value of a variable after processing an event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

There is an image, you can change the perspective of the image and you can still move this image. There is also the possibility to enter data from JavaScript into the Cookie, so that when updating the page you could save the changed coordinates of the control elements.
But there is a problem, I do not know how to correctly implement the changes made to the system when when the cookies are not empty (166 lines js), so that the coordinates of the control elements are not reset in the original position when updating the page.
Please tell me how correctly to organize entering of changed coordinates control elements in a status when when cookies not empty?

In advance I am very grateful for the help and I apologize for the bad English.

Example link http://jsfiddle.net/kbQPW/40/